# How to properly add SSL certificate from openSSL in localhost using Xammp and Wordpress with 8080 port

Tags: wordpress, rest, https, woocommerce, xampp

I am trying to build an application that will communicate with  WooCommerce via WordPress. For this purpose I have decided to use WordPress REST API plugin which requires me to genarate WooCommerce API key in order to communicate with my app.But when I press the generate key on WooCommerce settings page, nothing happens.

So I did some researches and came to know that I have to work on a protected site in order to acheive it (https). Only issue I am working on a localhost using Xammp and in order to make Xammp work on my machine I had to set my localhost on the 8080 port. so when I connect to my localhost I write http://localhost:8080/wordpress/. Since I don't yet want to spend on the project I followed instruction from [this link](https://x86x64.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/creating-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate/) in order to create my openSSL certificate. One thing to notice is that I set localhost:8080/wordpress as my common name in the certificate. I don't know if that was a good choice.

Then, following instruction from [this other link](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-8.htm#enable%20pfx%20no%20binding), I have enabled the new certificate on a Server and set my site to work on https. Only issue is that I get an error from xammp saying "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies..." when I start appache and if I call http://localhost:443/wordpress/ it says Bad request!. Can someone help please??